# duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  H:\OzelDersim\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1019: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
H:\OzelDersim\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1019: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\Emre Hmrc\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\0d3beb61e3dde971f53232b7b0aae803\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        H:\OzelDersim\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        H:\OzelDersim\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: `duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity'` remove both `layout_anchorGravity` or just the duplicate one from resources then tell us what happened after that.

Comment: In the future, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

In the module **build.gradle (app)**, add *support:design* in **dependencies**:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

**Replace the version** with the one used in your module and don't forget to **Sync**.

*[To check the latest version or for more information.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#design)*

Answer (score -1):

In your module build.gradle file check for a line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

remove it and rebuild.

---

I encountered the same error today after adding the default "SettingsActivity" files. The wizard inserted this line in the build.gradle file, causing the error.

Hint: use a version control system, it helps to discover such subtle errors easily.

Comment: Removing support-v4 helps?